# How to make a button look like a link in ZK

Tags: java, html, mvvm, zk, zul

So what i want is to bind `label` and `onClick` event of a link to a java bean in ZK.
So i tried

```
<a onClick="@command('reset')"/>
```

But `<a>` does not have `label` attribute.

`<button>` has both `label` and `onClick` but it show up as button which it is...

```
<button label="@bind(vm.value)" onClick="@command('reset')"/>
```

So how to make a button look like a link in ZK ?

I am using mvvm model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZK's ‘a‘ Component does, in fact, have a [‘label‘ attribute](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Essential%20Components/A).

```
<a label="@bind('vm.value')" onClick="@command('reset')"/>
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a `@load` instead of `@bind` when using non-input tags.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you  use `<label>` instead of `<a>` for link.

```
   <label style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: underline;"
    value="@bind(vm.value)" onClick="@command('pickFromMember')" />
```

you can also prefer @Sean Connolly answer `<a>` tag also have label attribute

```
  <a label="@bind('vm.value')" onClick="@command('reset')"/>
```

Comment: Strongly disagree with this approach. Using the  ‘a‘ tag comes with so much browser support beyond these two CSS styles.

Comment: Actually  @SeanConnolly i dont check this <a> tag have label  attribute But user  put question <a> tag does't have label attribute.so i suggest this